# eclipse - "Select Working Set" for "Open Declaration"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse, you can set a **working set** when looking at a call tree to filter out directories that you don't care about.

You can do the same when searching.

Is it possible to set a **working set** for the command **Open Declaration**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this has not been implemented. [Bug 407881](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=407881) is on file for it. (Contributions to implement things like this are welcome!)